# Direct energy weapon vs kinetic energy

Tags: energy, laser, laser-interaction

Good day, 
I would love to ask this question. Lets say that I have a energy source capable of delivering 10^30 watts with capacitors to match it and I would like to use this energy as a weapon (sort of like a death star).

Now the question, is it realistic to deliver all this energy through laser as a direct energy deposition (like death star), or is it not realistic and the only way to deliver this energy is through using thet energy to accelerate some object near to c and using it as a kinetic energy weapon? (fast projectile)?

Thank you really very much for your answers,

Have a nice day

Comment: Unless you are willing to accept *very* short pulses that don't deliver much, there are really astoundingly huge technological breakthroughs needed to get to *"Lets say that I have a energy source capable of delivering 10^30 watts"* with any kind of system. So you are going to be simple assuming something you want without any firm technological foundation for that assumptions. Which means you can have it either way.

Comment: The big issue is efficiency. Lasers are about 10% efficient in converting electricity to light. So you will get $10^{29}$ W of laser and $9\cdot 10^{29}$ W of heat - you better dissipate that heat efficiently, or you will be more vaporized than the target. Coilguns for accelerating masses are more efficient, but I have yet to see any good bounds in any paper.